# getting books based on author, translator, compiler

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

1. `books_table`
2. `author_table`
3. `author_compiled_relation`

QUERY ITSELF:

```
SELECT
    b.id            'id',
    b.auth_id       'auther_id',
    b.t_auth_id     't_auth_id',
    b.unique_name   'unique_name',
    b.native_name   'native_name',
    a.id            'auth_id',
    ar.book_id      'ar_bookid',
    ar.auth_id      'ar_authid'
FROM
    books                   b,
    authors                 a,
    authors_compile_rel     ar
WHERE
    b.auth_id   = ".$auth_id."
    OR
    b.t_auth_id = ".$bq_details['t_auth_id']."
    OR
    ar.auth_id  = ".$auth_id."
    OR
    b.id        = ar.book_id
    AND
    b.status    = '1'
    ORDER by id DESC
```

**The above query is not working for what i want stated below:**

1:  books_table (id, name, author, translator)
2:  author_table (id, name)
3:  author_compiled_relation (author, booksid)

i have entered the book in fruit table along with `author id`.
when i make query to get the books of the author it is working fine without any issue.
and also to get the translators books under its name is working fine.

now i want to get the books compiled by so and so.
in `author_compiled_relation` i have entered the `booksid` & `author`.

now what i want to make one query so if the author has the books as author or translator or as compiler it will show the books under the respected author id.

i have made the `author_compiled_relation` table because compiler can be more than one.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

It's done.... i got it working now and the answer is as below:

```
$query      = "
SELECT books.id, books.unique_name, books.native_name, books.auth_id,
books.t_auth_id, books.status, ar.auth_id, ar.book_id
FROM
  books, authors_compiler_relation ar
WHERE
  books.status = 1
AND
  ar.auth_id = ".$auth_id."
AND
  ar.book_id = books.id
OR
  books.auth_id = ".$auth_id."
OR
  books.t_auth_id = ".$auth_id."
ORDER by id DESC";
```